# Assembly x86 - Convert short int to int (WORD to DWORD)

Tags: assembly, matrix, x86

I have a matrix in C called m: **m = {{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}}**

But m is a **WORD (short int)** type and I need to convert every element of the matrix in a DWORD type (int) variable called **DWORD[number]** to show it.

Why? because the exercise is like that and doesn't let any modification.

Anywone knows how to do it? Thank you very much.

**Edit:**
One way to do that, as [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael) said using the instruction **MOVSX** like this:

```
MOVSX destination, source
```

Where source needs to be smaller than destination. However, in this example the first iteration of the matrix will be:

```
iter:
    MOV esi, 0    
    MOV bx, WORD[m+esi]
    MOVSX eax, bx
    MOV DWORD[number], eax
    ADD esi, 2
    CMP Register1, DimMatrix
    JLE iter
```

Where **Register1**, and **Register2** are your index registers to crawl the matrix.

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with the [`MOVSX` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_206.html).

Comment: If you've got SSE4.1 or AVX you could use `PMOVSX` to sign extend multiple values with a single instruction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll to explain, finally, how to achieve this. For future posts. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: You can do `movsx eax, word [m+esi]` too.

Comment: @Joanmacat: If you answer your own question, post an answer rather than editing it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: One way to do that, as Michael said using the instruction MOVSX like this:

```
MOVSX destination, source
```

Where source needs to be smaller than destination. However, in this example the first iteration of the matrix will be:

```
iter:
    MOV esi, 0    
    MOV bx, WORD[m+esi]
    MOVSX eax, bx
    MOV DWORD[number], eax
    ADD esi, 2
    CMP Register1, DimMatrix
    JLE iter
```

Where Register1, and Register2 are your index registers to crawl the matrix.